# Cannot Resolve Symbol RecyclerViewActions / RecyclerViewMatcher

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write tests for a recycler view in my android app. I am getting a cannot resolve symbol error for "RecyclerViewActions" and "RecyclerViewMatcher."

Here is the helper method in my test where the "cannot resolve symbol" error is being thrown.

`````
````// Convenience helper
public static RecyclerViewMatcher withRecyclerView(final int recyclerViewId) {
    return new RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId);
}````
`````

Here is my import where the error is also being thrown

`import static androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions;`

Here is my app level build.gradle dependencies:

`````
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}````
`````

Answer (score 2):

Add in app level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

    //Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerViewActions` and `RecyclerViewMatcher` classes are placed under `espresso-contrib` dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation( "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion")
}
```

Source: [androidx-test-libraries/test-setup](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/test-setup)